# Convert character to integer OR get ASCII code of character in R

Tags: r, integer, ascii

In C/C++ we just do `nX = cX - " "` to obtain integer `nX` from character `cX`.

How do we do it in R ?

Comment: charToRaw("A") # [1] 41

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`charToRaw` returns a vector with the integer code, without taking into account any declared encoding.

See: `??charToRaw` for more help and related functions.

Example:

```
charToRaw("A")
#[1] 41

charToRaw("AB")
# [1] 41 42
is.vector(charToRaw("AB"))
# TRUE
```